# uniform convergence of series $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+k^2x} $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

I know that the series
$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\vphantom{\Large A}1\ +\ k^{2}\,x}$
is converges uniformly on $\left(a,\infty\right)$ for $a > 0$, but how can I show that it does not converge uniformly on $\left(0,\infty\right)$?

Comment: Hello, welcome to Maths.SE. I have changed the formatting of the title so as to make it take up less vertical space -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the series is uniformly convergent on $(0,+\infty)$ then 
$$\lim_{x\to0} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+k^2x}= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} 1\, \text{is finite}$$
which is obviously wrong. Conclude.

**Added**
By the definition the series is uniformly convergent if
$$0=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{x\geq0}\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{1+k^2x}\geq\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{1}{1+k^2\times0}=\lim_{n\to\infty}n=\infty$$
which's wrong

Comment: You mean interchanging of limit? Thanks but Actually this problem is exercise before uniform convergence and interchange of limit. So can you show me another explanation without changing of limit if possible? And thanks again.

Comment: hint says think about $(S_{n}-S_{n-1})(\frac{1}{n^2})$ but I cannot understand any of it.

Comment: @quicksilver I edited my answer.